# How to deploy cloudfoundry to AWS?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

This has me stumped.

I followed the instructions to the dot on http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/ec2/

I used Ruby 1.9.3, Windows 7 64 bit.

Here is the error I get

```
C:\code\CloudfoundryAWS>bosh aws create
←[0m←[31m←[0m←[31mFailed to load plugin C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_aws-1.5.0.pre.805/lib/bosh/cli/commands/aws.rb: No such file or directory - /dev/null←[0m←[0m
```

Yes, the weird arrows are part of the output.

There is a file called `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_aws-1.5.0.pre.805/lib/bosh/cli/commands/aws.rb`

There is no file called `/dev/null`. Im not sure which one Ruby / Bosh is implying.

Comment: FYI I've opened [a pull request](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/361) that I think will fix the issue for you.  I'm not positive though because it looks like you're missing a stack trace (and I don't have a Windows machine available to try it out).

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Sharing so that others may find it useful. It was `/dev/null` indeed. I created a `/dev` folder in `C:\` and it worked.